# AWS Lambda, copy between s3 buckets with python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

So Im writing a lambda fuction, witch is triggered by an S3 PUT,

```
import datetime
import boto3
import botocore

#boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', level='DEBUG')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    src_bucket_name=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print src_bucket_name
    file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    split_string = file.split('/')
    file_string = split_string[-1].split('_')
    fecha_str = event['Records'][0]['eventTime']
    fecha_real=datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')+ datetime.timedelta(hours=-6)

    new_path='PATH/'+file_string[0].lower()+'/'+str(fecha_real.year)+'/'+str(fecha_real.month)+'/'+split_string[-1]


    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': src_bucket_name,
        'Key': file
    }

    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, DST_BUCKET_NAME, new_path)
```

when I run the code I get
**ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found**

the file does exists 
[file in source_bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR2iJ.png)

Could you please tell what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I gave admin permissions to the role I'm using and still having the same error.

UPDATE-CLOSED:

I deleted the role, made a new one, change the code on the copy part to this:

```
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': src_bucket_name,
    'Key': file
}

r = s3_client.copy_object(
    Bucket=[DST_BUCKET_NAME],
    CopySource=copy_source,
    Key=new_path
)
```

and it worked!

Comment: Have you assigned permissions to your Lambda function to access S3? Your error can mean that the resource does not exist OR you do not have permission to access it.

Comment: Are you sure `SRC_BUCKET_NAME` is the same as `src_bucket_name`?

Comment: Hey @johnhanley I gave admin permisions to the role Im using, still having troubles.

Comment: @kichik yes sorry, editing my post now

Comment: Look at this line "'Bucket': SRC_BUCKET_NAME," you should be using lower case letters to match src_bucket_name=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

Comment: Follow this document, Step 2.3.2 and test your Lambda function manually. This will speed up figuring out what is wrong. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-upload-deployment-pkg.html